# Salesforce Parent ID Trigger

Tags: triggers, salesforce

I have a question, I hope I can tell you clearly my problem.

Regarding the parentfunction at the account, I added **two fields** to the account **ParentID (15)** and **ParentIDLong (18)**. 
The ParentID field is a formulafield with the code below.

```
IF(LEN(Parent.Id) < 1, Id, 
IF(LEN(Parent.Parent.Id) < 1, (Parent.Id), 
IF(LEN(Parent.Parent.Parent.Id) < 1, (Parent.Parent.Id), 
IF(LEN(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Id) < 1, (Parent.Parent.Parent.Id), 
IF(LEN(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Id) < 1,    (Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Id), 
IF(LEN(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Id) < 1, (Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Id), 
IF(LEN(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Id) < 1, (Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Id), 
IF(LEN(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Id) < 1,(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Id),">7"))))))))
```

Now I need the ParentLongID, unfortunately its not possible to change the formula, because I will get an error which is "the formula is too big".

I wrote a trigger which posted the long ID into the field ParentLongID (code below).

```
Trigger SetParentIDLong on Account (before update) {

FOR (Account Acc : Trigger.new) {

   Account oldAcc = Trigger.oldMap.get(Acc.Id);

String idStr = Acc.ParentID__c;
Id idVal = idStr;
idStr = idVal;

If (oldAcc.ParentId__c != Acc.ParentID__c) {
    Acc.ParentIdLong__c = idStr;
}
```

So far so good, it works if I create the hierarchy from the top to the bottom.

**Example:**

MotherCompany ParentIDLong: blank

Daughter1 ParentIDLong: 001b000000XUTQAAA5

Daughter2 ParnetIDLong: 001b000000XUTQAAA5

But if I add a MotherMotherCompany

**Example:**

MotherMotherCompany ParentIDLong: blank

MotherCompany ParentIDLong: 001m000000Ft35yAAB

Daughter1 ParentIDLong: 001b000000XUTQAAA5

Daughter2 ParnetIDLong: 001b000000XUTQAAA5

The trigger doesn't work, because the trigger changed only the ParentIDLong at the Mothercompany.

Its possible to change with trigger all other companies as well?

Thanks,
Sascha

Comment: Im open for any other ideas, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create the relationship of all other accounts you would need to have an update account on this trigger so your trigger is called recursively.

like this:

```
Trigger SetParentIDLong on Account (before update) {

FOR (Account Acc : Trigger.new) {
 Account oldAcc = Trigger.oldMap.get(Acc.Id);

 String idStr = Acc.ParentID__c;
 Id idVal = idStr;
 idStr = idVal;

 If (oldAcc.ParentId__c != Acc.ParentID__c) {
  Acc.ParentIdLong__c = idStr;
  update Acc; //this line would call again your trigger
              //recursively until the last Account
 }
```

try and let us know how it went

Comment: Unfortunately, I got an error - Error:Apex trigger SetKonzernIDLong caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: SetKonzernIDLong: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.SObjectException: DML statment cannot operate on trigger.new or trigger.old: Trigger.SetKonzernIDLong

Comment: Then let me work on a different approach of this, I will also try it so we can be sure it works, I'll post again to show you the new solution

Answer (score 0):

OK
Let's try this:

```
Trigger SetParentIDLong on Account (before update) {
    List<Id> accids = new List<Id>();

    for(Account a : Trigger.New){
        accids.add(a.Id);
    }

    List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id,ParentId__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accids];

    for(Account child : accounts){
        Account oldAcc = Trigger.oldMap.get(child.Id);

        String idStr = child.ParentID__c;
        Id idVal = idStr;
        idStr = idVal;

        if(oldAcc.ParentId__c != child.ParentID__c) {
        child.ParentIdLong__c = idStr;
        update child; //this line would call again your trigger
                    //recursively until the last Account
        }

    }
}
```

I just changed some names and created a new list of accounts based on the trigger.new because we cannot update the trigger.new,

Let's see if this works.

Keep me posted

Comment: Thanks for your code, but now nothing is happen, the ParentIdLong__c keep blank in all accounts.

Comment: Do you have some ideas?

Comment: Hi Levementum, do you know some more ideas? I don't know how can I fix the problem. Thanks.